# How to use xs:any keyword in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to make the game data file use XML and XSD.
It must be extensible.

xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<enemy xmlns="rubtub2314@gmail.com/Enemy_Data.xml"
      xmlns:schema="rubtub2314@gmail.com/Enemy_Data.xml">
  <info id="0" name="warrior"> 
    <atk>1</atk>
    <def>1</def>
    <hp>1</hp>
    <spd>1</spd>
    **<anti_magic>1</anti_magic>**
  </info>
  <info id="1" name="archer">
    <atk>1</atk>
    <def>1</def>
    <hp>1</hp>
    <spd>1</spd>
  </info>
</enemy>
```

xsd :

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns="rubtub2314@gmail.com/Enemy_Data.xsd"
            targetNamespace="rubtub2314@gmail.com/Enemy_Data.xml"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"> 
  <xs:element name="enemy">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="info">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="atk" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
              <xs:element name="def" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
              <xs:element name="hp" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
              <xs:element name="spd" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
              **<xs:any minOccurs="0"/>**
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But my any keyword does not work. It make Just one line error message

> 'rubtub2314@gmail.com/Enemy_Data.xml:anti_magic' element does not declared. (<- it maybe not correct translation)

Why do I get this error?

I want to create an extensible XML that can add other parameters under the info element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Wildcard_details) of xs:any:

> {process contents} controls the impact on ·assessment· of the information items allowed by wildcards, as follows:
>
> - **strict**
>   There must be a top-level declaration for the item available, or the item must have an xsi:type, and the item must be ·valid· as appropriate.
> - **skip**
>   No constraints at all: the item must simply be well-formed XML.
> - **lax**
>   If the item has a uniquely determined declaration available, it must be ·valid· with respect to that definition, that is, ·validate· if you can, don't worry if you can't.

So use "skip" or "lax" as a parameter in the following line:

```
<xs:any processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```